# jquery each() function in AS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Though flash is dying technology I still have to finish my project :)))

How to implement for each loop in AS3 that gives me the index of the element in the array, much like the jquery each() function does it

```
jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )
```

I use this

```
for each(var myObj:* in myArray)
{ 
     // do some stuff with myObj
}
```

How to use stateme like this myArray.splice(index, 1) in for each???

Or is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work.

```
var arr:Array = new Array();
arr[1] = true;
arr[5] = true;
arr.forEach(function (item:*, index:int, array:Array)
{
    if(item != undefined)
    {
        callback(index, item);          
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `.each()` is just an object iterator that does some additional checking for you. You should be able to get away with a syntax like:

```
var i = 0;
for ( property in object ) {
    callback( i++, object[property] )
}
```

Though, I don't know how AS3 works, but keep in mind that there is no order to object properties in JavaScript.

Comment: Yup i know this solution. The thing was to avoid using creating separate indexes like i, j, k, t etc... :))

Comment: Are you trying to loop through an array or an object? An array should have int keys, so you have the index?

Comment: Array is indeed an array in As3. Objects have integer indexes. But AS3 arrays are sparse arrays so object in midlle can be undefined like this arr[0] = obj1 , arr[1] = undefined arr[2] = obj2

Comment: In as3 we use Object with JSON syntax like this {"index1": value1, index2":value2}

Comment: But anyways I guess there is no way to do it in AS3, without using separate index counters

Comment: I'm confused about your question, still. When you call `.each()`, all that happens is jQuery decides what type of object you are passing in, and iterates through it, either using int keys or object properties. It's just a loop wrapped in a function call. That's it!

Comment: Ok if no other answers today i will delete the question. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Why not using the [forEach](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#forEach%28%29) function belonging to the Array object that will executes a function on each item in the array.

Here a live sample using it : http://wonderfl.net/c/mLhCM

ex:

```
var ar:Array = ["hello", 1, "world", 2];
ar.forEach(
   function(elm:*, index:int, arr:Array):void {
            trace("got elm : "+elm+" at index : "+index);
   }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simple `for...in` loop:

```
var arr:Array = [2,1,5,0,0,0,87,8,110];

for (var i:String in arr)
{
    trace("Value:" + arr[i] + " at " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for(var i:int=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
    var myObj = myArray[i];
}
```

it's hard to know exactly what to use unless you specify what you wish to achieve :)

Answer (score 1):

a "for each" should not be used to iterate through an indexed array, the standard for(var i=0;xxx;xxx) should be used.
If for whatever reason you still find yourselff needing a for each loop then this would be how to get the index

```
var arr:Array = ['00','11','22','33','44','55','66','77','88','99']
for each(var o:Object in arr){
    trace(arr.indexOf(o))
}
```

Another option would be to use the for in loop

```
for (var key:String in arr){
    trace(key)
}
```

Comment: What is your reasoning behind saying you shouldn't use for each on the array?